# Combinatorics: number of functions/predicates satisfying a sum on their entries

Tags: combinatorics

Given integers $n,m$,
is there a closed form expression for the cardinality of the following set?
$$\left\{ p : \{1,\dots,n\}^2 \rightarrow \{true,false\} \quad \Bigg| \sum_{i,j,k \in \{1,\dots,n\}} I(p(i,j) \wedge p(j,k) \wedge p(k,i)) = m\right\}$$

where $I$ is the indicator function mapping $true$ and $false$ to $1$ and $0$ respectively.

I suspect the answer is negative. If so, what would be a good argument for that?

By closed form I mean an expression that takes *time* independent of $n$ and $m$ to compute. Note that this is easy for simpler formulas. For example,

$$\#\left\{ p : \{1,\dots,n\}^2 \rightarrow \{true,false\} \quad \Bigg| \sum_{i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}} I(p(i,j))  = m\right\} = \binom{n^2}{m} $$

(we simply choose $m$ pairs out of the $n^2$ possible ones for which $p$ will be true).

Comment: How do you sum the terms? That is, what is, for example, $false+true$?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. 1 for true, 0 for false.

Comment: Hm, number of graphs with exactly $m$ $3$-cycles with loops..